# Angular.js count item iterations when filtering objects with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, count, duplicates, filtering, ng-options

working on a list filtering with Angular, where listing the items based on region and creating an option select to list these regionsm where I have to remove duplications, and will need a count number next to the region name, which represents how many items from the same region.

I found this thread : [How to count unique results based on a particular properties within ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172928/how-to-count-within-ng-options) but its not working when removing the duplications.

Heres is my select

```
<select ng-options="item.region as item.region for item in items | unique: 'region'" ng-model="catFilter">
```

Here is my app.js

```
var regionSort = angular.module('regionSort', [
    'regionSort.controllers'
]);

regionSort.filter('unique', function() {

    return function(items, filterOn) {

        if (filterOn === false) {
            return items;
        }

        if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
            var hashCheck = {},
                newItems = [];

            var extractValueToCompare = function(item) {
                if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
                    return item[filterOn];
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            };

            angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
                var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;
                var count = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                    if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                        isDuplicate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isDuplicate) {
                    newItems.push(item);
                }

            });
            items = newItems;
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```

Does anybody have any idea how should I solve this? Thanks in advance!!

Item structure is pretty simple like :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Name",
        "desc": "Description",
        "price": 700,
        "priceold": 1080,
        "persons": 10,
        "discount": 35,
        "vote": "9,3",
        "image": "https://someige.jpg",
        "url": "http://someurl.com",
        "region": "XXX"
    }, ...
]
```

Comment: Please provide items structure.

Comment: It is updated, thanks